# Key length must be between 40 and 1024 bit

Tags: java, encryption, jce, rc4-cipher

I am getting following exception in my password encryption and decryption java file.

I got the solution for this issue in most of the website is replace existing security policy file with Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

I did that also but still the same error is coming.

But the same code is working fine in jdk1.6 with Linux OS. I have copied latest 1.7 compatible Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files from website.

> JDK Version - jdk1.7.0_25
>       Server OS - Linux
>       
>       Exception:
>       java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length must be between 40 and 1024 bit

Comment: SecretKeySpec secretkeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(HexDecode(s1),
     "RC4");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkeyspec);
abyte0 = cipher.doFinal(HexDecode(s2));

Comment: am getting exception in Cipher.getInstance("RC4") this line

Comment: What is the length of the result of HexDecode(s1) / what does HexDecode do ? I don't get an exception in the getInstance() line. However I do get an exception with this code: new SecretKeySpec("1234".getBytes(), "RC4");  (in that example, the key is 32 bit)

Comment: if i put this System.out.println(HexDecode(s1).length); it is printing 512. In the above code  s1 is encrypted string.

Comment: private static byte[] HexDecode(String s) {
  byte[] abyte0 = new byte[s.length() / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < abyte0.length; ++i) {
   byte byte0 = (byte) ((getByteValue(s.charAt(i * 2)) << 4) + getByteValue(s
     .charAt(i * 2 + 1)));
   abyte0[i] = byte0;
  }

Comment: I hope my answer was helpful; if yes, press the green checkmark. To help others in the future, consider editing your question with the 2nd and 5th comment.

Answer (score 0):

You explained in the comments that the key passed is 512 bytes long. The error message is "Key length must be between 40 and 1024 bit".

512 bytes * 8 bit = 4096 bits. Your key is indeed too long.

If you're not decoding stuff that was encoded earlier with keys longer than 1024 bits, then use this code to cut off at 128 bytes (= 1024 bits):

```
byte[] key = HexDecode(s1);
if (key.length > 128)
{
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 128);
}
SecretKeySpec secretkeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "RC4");
```

Comment: can anyone please provide the solution for this?

Comment: @Muralidharan well, you could just cut it off at 1024 bits, i.e. at 128 bytes if you know that the key is longer. However what about stuff that is already encrypted before the switch to JDK7? That one would then be out of reach. In that case, I'd suggest to use your own RC4 implementation, google for "java rc4 implementation".

Comment: after applied above suggestion new exception is as follows, Illegal key size or default parameters

Comment: @Muralidharan to verify that the "Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" are working correctly, do this: System.out.println(Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("RC4")); it should output 2147483647. If not, maybe you installed the files in the wrong directory. If yes, then please reproduce the problem by writing SSCCE (see http://sscce.org ) code, edit it into your question or upload it somewhere, and ping me here and I'll look again. I really want to help, but can't reproduce the newer problem here.